# Laravel - relation to get data from far table

Tags: php, laravel

When I get a product, how do I get the corresponding group name from the options_group in the product model?

**Product model**

```
public function options()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Option::class, "product_options", "product_id", "option_id");
    }
```

**Option model**

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class, "product_options", "option_id", "product_id")->using(ProductOptions::class);
}

public function optionsGroups()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(OptionsGroup::class, "option_group_id ");
}
```

**OptionsGroup model**

```
public function options()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Option::class, "option_group_id");
}
```

i want something like this

```
{
  "title": "product name",
  "optionGroups": [
    {
      "name": "Size",
      "options": [
        {
          "name": "XL",
         },
        {
          "name": "L",
         }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

[image]

Comment: You need to made relation with one by one model 

Product > Product Option > Option > Option Group

in Product::With(product_option.option.option_group)

Answer (score 1):

okay you have to make your product model like this

Product Model:

```
public function optionsGroups()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(OptionsGroup::class, Option::class);
}
```

and
Option Model:

```
public function optionGroup()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(OptionsGroup::class, "option_group_id");
}
```

and

OptionsGroup Model:

```
public function options()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Option::class, "option_group_id");
}
```

Then, you can retrieve the data and construct the desired JSON structure like this:

```
$product = Product::find($productId);

$productData = [
    'title' => $product->title,
    'optionGroups' => [],
];

$optionGroups = $product->optionsGroups;

foreach ($optionGroups as $optionGroup) {
    $options = [];

    foreach ($optionGroup->options as $option) {
        $options[] = [
            'name' => $option->name,
            'price' => $option->price,
        ];
    }

    $productData['optionGroups'][] = [
        'name' => $optionGroup->name,
        'options' => $options,
    ];
}

return response()->json($productData);
```

Replace `$productId` with the actual ID of the product you want to retrieve